# C# How to implement a Time To Live function to a big list's content

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, ttl

I'm building an app that listens to Wamp protocol messages and stores them in a `List<MySpecialClass>`. Since the traffic is, quite frankly, wild (About 1-1.5 thousand messages in a minute or two), I would like to implement some way of cleaning this list automatically of terminated entries.

My idea was to provide `MySpecialClass` with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch isTerminated` field. Recieving a Wamp message that some entry was terminated would run a `isTerminated.StartNew()`. And a regular (but much less frequent than 60s) loop through the `List<MySpecialClass>` would make sure to `List.Remove()` any `MySpecialClass` that has `isTerminated.ElapsedMilliseconds>60000`.

I should note, that due to some complex stuff the terminated entry can then be reinstated again with another Wamp message, which, in accordance to my idea, would call a `isTerminated.Reset()`.

I'd go ahead and do it, but I'm new at this, I'm not sure what kind of trouble I'm getting myself into with the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch. Would it cut my memory usage or increase it?

I'd love to hear feedback on this method I'm thinking about as well as some suggestions about how one should go about cleaning their lists. Cheers!

**EDIT**

I guess I'm prone to overthinking problems, sorry for your trouble. A Pikoh's idea in the comments is what I needed.

Comment: It honestly depends on how you implement this.  Without any base examples or a specific problem though, this is a bit too broad of a question for this site.  Maybe [edit] in a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm only contemplating what to do at this point. Can't wrap my head around how to approach this. Will definitely edit in any of my attempts though, sure.

Comment: There are probably a lot of ways to implement this. But at a first thought, what about just storing a timestamp in your class when that Wamp message is recieved and then, in that another timer/loop check if that timestamp is expired?

Comment: @Pikoh I can't do that because a message does not expire arbitrarily due to some time period. It only does that when another message, contradicting the previous, arrives. And then, oh what a twist, another message can arrive which would reinstate the original one. =X

Comment: Ok,so when the first message (contradicting the previous), arrives, you set the timestamp to that moment in a property of your class. If another message comes to reinstate the original, you just set the timestamp to null. Then, a timer would run the clean code,where you could check if between the timestamp and now at least a fixed amount of time has passed. (I hope you get what i mean )

Comment: @Pikoh Yeah. Was easier than I thought, thanks! I'm overthinking too much xD Thanks  a lot. Gotta rest for a while, this one project is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I could just add a timestamp field in my class, that would show when the message got terminated and check that, which is marginally better than my idea. Thanks Pikoh.